# In docker swarm, every worker has it's own /var with different data compared to other workers, so the workers are different, how can I handle it?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

On an Ubuntu image,
There is a **php** code where a web server (**NGINX**) gets an photo from end user and uploads the photo on **/var**

I create an image from the above image

Now with docker swarm, where multiple replicas (**workers**) of the above image are created as containers on different servers,
How can the user *(An android application which gets photo from user and upload it on server)* access his/her uploaded image on the same server (**worker**) where he/she uploaded his/her image?

There would be several replicas with several **/var**
Every worker will have it's own **/var** with different data compared to one other worker

Comment: not a straight forward task. Session affinity/peristence won't help alot. Most easy would be to use a shared database. Otherwise, you need to work with volumes, which is tricky cross server. But I am voting for close as opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 3 options:

1. NFS: The docker local volume driver supports syntax for mounting a nfs share. Have a server somewhere with an nfs share, and mount the share into each container as a volume.
2. RClone: Store the files in a AWS S3 or Minio (on prem) S3 bucket. Install rclone's docker volume plugin on all worker nodes to mount the storage as a volume the service can access.
3. GlusterFS: Build a Gluster FS cluster and to store the files install one of the opensource or available glusterfs docker volume plugins.